# Should one reference a source library under MIT license if a code was grabed out of it and was changed

Tags: licensing

a library that depends on jquery was created. After that, a version where all dependant calls were replaced with original jquery code. Most parts of such code were removed as redundant. Should be jquery somehow mentioned in such case?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more exactly what the situation is? If you're incorporating code obtained from jQuery then of course you have to reference jQuery/its contributors!

Comment: @curiousdannii It was an old version 1.7.1. There was no copyright just reference to the license

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MIT license does not require that you in some way reference the original project when you copy some code.

The MIT license *does* require that you copy the copyright and license text along with the code that you copy. Depending on how the copyright statement is formulated, this can become effectively a reference to the original project.

Answer (score 1):

If what was done was to start using A's code, and gradually replacing it by own (rewritten) code, written by referencing the original A code, the result is a derivative of the original.